# hibernate query for selecting multiple rows from a table

Tags: mysql, hql

Am new to hybernate Query Language(HQL).Am trying to search multiple values and returns multiple rows accordingly

I have a table with name and id
and have to search with name with mutiple values
Like

```
Select * from employeedata where employename like '%siva%' and '%laya%'
```

I used above query but returning the data for siva only.
Or any other ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want an `or` condition.

```
employeeName like 'expression' OR employeeName like 'expression'
```